# How to fire mouse click event on a JavaFX ListView?

Tags: listview, events, javafx, onmouseclick

How to fire a single and double mouse click events on the first (or any other) item of a `javafx.scene.control.ListView`?

I want to receive the event like this:

```
getListView().setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
    switch (mouseEvent.getClickCount()) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding. Events are not fired on the items of the `ListView`, but on the `ListCell`s that display the items. `ListCell`s may be constructed dynamically and reused, so there may not be a event target corresponding to a particular item.

If you get your hands on the correct node, you could however fire an event using [`Event.fireEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#fireEvent-javafx.event.EventTarget-javafx.event.Event-):

```
Node target = ...
MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, ...);
Event.fireEvent(target, mouseEvent);
```

You could also find the `ListCell`s using [`lookupAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-):

```
Set<Node> listCells = listView.lookupAll(".list-cell");
```

and use [`ListCell.getItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#getItem--) and [`ListCell.getIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/IndexedCell.html#getIndex--) to determine the correct one.

But since the event listener is added to the `ListView` finding the correct `ListCell` may not be necessary.